# App not compatible anymore even when system reqs are satisfied

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play, compatibility

I was working on an Android application and it was working fine for devices with Android 8+ (API 26) but after some updates, the Google Play Store is showing "This app is no longer compatible with your device. Contact the developers for more info." Even though I didn't change the system requirements.
Here's my gradle code:

```
android {
    namespace = "com.company.test"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.company.test"
        minSdk = 26
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 12
        versionName = "2.2.1"
...
```

Manifest file:

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:allowClearUserData="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@drawable/img_app_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/img_app_logo"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.test"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:targetApi="34">
...
```

I tried to upload the app to the Xiaomi's app store, GetApps, but when I upload the APK file for my latest version, for example 2.2.0, it uploads older version 2.1.2! I have no idea how that's happening even though I'm uploading the same file for Google Play and GetApps

I looked on the internet for solutions but none of them worked for me.
I also want you to note that this problem is only occurring on some Xiaomi Redmi devices.
I tested it on:

Redmi Note 8 with MIUI version 12.5.2 and API version 30 [Not working]

Redmi Note 9 with MIUI version 12.5.5 and API version 30 [Working]

Redmi Note 10 Pro with MIUI version 13.0.7 and API version 31 [Not working]

Redmi Note 11 with MIUI version 14.0.5 and API version 32 [Working]

I also tried it on a Xiaomi POCO X3 NFC with MIUI version 14.0.2 and API version 31 [Working]

Comment: Did you increase the versionCode along with the versionName?

Comment: Yes, of course, I did, otherwise Google Play store won't accept the newer version

Comment: Check the permissions in your merged manifest. You may have added a permission by updating or adding a library.

Comment: I have returned all libraries and permission to what it was before but still not working.
Also, the permissions I added I specified the required Android version like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="32"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
```